# STL Map doesn't erase

Tags: c++, dictionary, erase

I have the following method in my program.

Weird thing is the data is not removed after I call erase.

Any idea?

```
map<int,obj>::iterator it = this->indexMap.find(id);
if(it != this->indexMap.end())
{
    int mapSize = this->indexMap.size();
    int dataSize = (*it).second.getDataMap().size();

    //copy data to another node | even when it doesn't get into this if condition, it does not remove the data
    if(mapSize> 1 && dataSize != 0)
    {
        it++;
        this->copyData(id,it->first);
        it--;
    }

    //remove peer | i've tried id and it, both does not work
    this->indexMap.erase(it);

    map<int,obj>::iterator iter = this->indexMap.find(id);
    if(iter == this->indexMap.end())
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
  ERROR
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: If `map::find()` cannot find an element in the container it returns an iterator to one past the last element i.e: `map::end()`, that is what you are getting, since the output is `ERROR`. Are you getting confused with what `find()` returns? From the code and output posted in the Q, it seems the element is indeed being removed.

Comment: what do you mean it is not removed? It looks to me like it is.

Comment: What if `it++` gives you `indexMap.end()`? Dereferencing `it` will cause UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This block:

```
map<int,obj>::iterator iter = this->indexMap.find(id);
if(iter == this->indexMap.end())
{
    cout << "ERROR" << endl;
}
```

prints out `ERROR` if an element with key `id` is not found in the map. Hence it has been removed.

Comment: @dupdupdup no problem, I know the feeling. You may want to accept the answer so that others don't waste time thinking your question is still unanswered.

Comment: sorry, i accepted the answer yesterday, but not sure why it was taken off, maybe due to latency issues. thanks anyway

Comment: @dupdupdup ah yes, there was some server weirdness yestarday.